# Autocomplete search in Django

Tags: jquery, django, django-views, autocomplete, extends

I am using autocomplete function to filter data,
from this site:

> https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

First I am using Django. everything work perfectly with this method if it is in page with no extends.

but if I use it in page which is inside a block extends it doesn't work!??

```
{% extends 'Home/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Home/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'Home/plugins/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'Home/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>
```

So it works when I delete  {% extends 'Home/base.html' %}?
what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just add the same links and script in the base.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Home/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'Home/plugins/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'Home/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>
```